# Scrollable text field in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to create a text field where I can display codes and snippets without wrapping text instead I want the text to scroll text along both x and y axis.
*I am trying to use following code but can't do that*

```
ScrollView:
    CodeInput:
        text:"abc"*30
        scroll_x: True
```

Comment: Have a look at the [ScrollView Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#module-kivy.uix.scrollview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


KV = '''
Screen:
    ScrollView:
        id: scroll
        CodeInput:
            size_hint: 1, None
            text: "abc"*3000
            height: max(self.minimum_height, scroll.height)
'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks this was also a problem. But I also want to scroll my code along x axis unlike stack overflow where we can add code without wrapping lines so that it's easy to understand code.                                                       Can you THANKS FOR YOUR HELP 